# Population of Dataset<Row> in java spark with reference from list of Maps

Tags: apache-spark, spark-java

I have a `Dataset<Row> df` with columns (`studentid,studentname,studentplace,student_strength`)

Sample Output now :

| studentid | studentname | studentplace | student_strength |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Roberta | marketstreet | null |
| 2 | Oliver | lincolnStreet | null |
| 3 | Shayna | Eaton | null |
| 4 | Fechin | Vaughan | null |

I have list of Map as below,

```
{1 = Student(1,11,Mathematics)},{2=Student(2,11,SocialScience)},{3=Student(3,11,Mathematics)},{4=Student(4,11,EnglishLiterature)}
```

key as `studentid` and values as `Student` object as below. for eg,

```
class Student
{
    String studentid;
    String student_age;
    String stdudent_strength
}
```

I wanted to map `student_strength` column in each row in dataset df from taking value from the map using `studentid` column.

For eg, for each row using student id get the `Student()` from map and populate student strength in the row, No Join just iterating this way.

So after this the out put would be something like below,

| studentid | studentname | studentplace | student_strength |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Roberta | marketstreet | Mathematics |
| 2 | Oliver | lincolnStreet | SocialScience |
| 3 | Shayna | Eaton | Mathematics |
| 4 | Fechin | Vaughan | EnglishLiterature |

Comment: Can you explain further, or add a sample of the input and the expected the answer

Comment: "map and populate student strength in the row, No Join just iterating this way" - why no join? Actually i think that it may be worth to create ds from Map and join it later with initial df